# Positioning page title next to menu button in a top bar

Tags: html, css

I am creating a top bar where I just want a menu icon in the left, the page title next to it and I will add a search bar in the right side but I will do that later.

I followed w3schools guide to create a collapsed sidebar and it works but I would like to achieve two more things:

- The menu icon is smaller than the bar itself where it is positioned. I would like it to increase its size so it fills the bar.
- I want the page title to be displayed next to it but I am not able to achieve this no matter where I place the  that contains it.

I am going to remove the sidepanel code as it is working and it does not have to do with my issue positioning the menu icon and the page title:

```css
#wrapper-header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #2E2D30;
}

#main-header {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  height: auto;
}

.page-title {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -35px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="wrapper-header">
  <div id="main-header">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
    <div class="page-title">Recientes</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for the  menu icon try adding some padding for example .openbtn{
  padding: 10px 30px;} . For the second question, could you clarify more? I mean you have the title to be on the left by 150px.

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle from your code but it's not running, can you update it in order to make easier to help?

Comment: It is running if you remove opacity:0; from the wrapper header.

Comment: Thanks fot the tip

Comment: And actually petoma I am not sure also about your first question. If you mean the inner size of the button's "icon", this is actually the &#9776; one, which you can change with another icon as content, and zero padding with an increasing font-size rules, on the button's class.

Comment: Thank you about your comments. I tried the padding solution but it didn't show the desire result. I also tried the "scale" solution that I received from the first answer and it worked. I was able as well to position the page title where I needed so this post has been solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically I had to change a little bit your css

```css
    #wrapper-header {
        color: white;
        font-size: 28px;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 65px;
        background-color: #2E2D30;
    }

    #main-header {
        position: relative;
    }

    .page-title {
        position: absolute;
        height: 20px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     }

     .openbtn {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        margin-top: 18px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        transform: scale(2);
      }
```

```html
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="wrapper-header">
  <div id="main-header">
<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
<div class="page-title">Recientes</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45pyot21/3/) or just run snippet code from the answer to see the result

NB: I used `transform: scale(2);` to fit the button to the navbar cause if you just change width and height the icon will remain too small

Let me know if it answer your question and if you need some further information

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked and solved the issue. I was able to fill the top bar and I could place the text next to it.

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer if this is the case :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look please, I think you are looking for something like this

```css
/* ------------ top menu --------------  */
.navbar{font-family:Arial; background-color:#4F0D1B;  border:0;  border-radius:0px}

.navbar-collapse{padding-left:0; padding-right:0;}
 .navbar-toggle{margin:7px; color:#fff}

.navbar{margin:0; z-index:999;}
ul.navbar-nav > li > a{color:#fff; padding:20px 30px; line-height: 30px; transition:all ease 0.5s; z-index: 99; min-width: 96px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; }


ul.navbar-nav > li a:hover, ul.navbar-nav > li.active, 
ul.nav .open > a:focus, ul.nav li > a:focus {background-color:#830F27; transition:all ease 0.5s;}

/* when clicked */
.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #830F27;

}

/* submenu style */
.navbar .dropdown-menu{z-index:999; min-width:100%; border:0; background-color:#4F0D1B}
.navbar .dropdown-menu  li a{text-align:left; padding:15px; color:#fff; }





/*  mega menu */ 
.mega-dropdown { position: static !important; }
.mega-dropdown-menu { z-index:999999;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  background-color:#7A0E23!important;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu ul{margin:0; padding:0}
.mega-dropdown-menu  li {color:#fff; list-style: outside none}

.mega-dropdown-menu  li  a{padding:5px!important; display:block!important;  }
.mega-dropdown-menu  li  a:hover{background-color:#4F0D1B!important}

a.title-submenu{font-weight:bold; color:rgba(0,0,0,.5); }


/* search form  */ 
.searchform{padding:10px 15px; float:right} 
.searchform .btn{ color:rgba(200,200,200,.5);border: 1px solid transparent; background-color:#830F27; }
.searchform .form-control{
 border:0; color:#fff;
 background-color:rgba(200,200,200,.1);
 width:120px!important;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
   transition: all .5s ease;
}
.searchform .form-control:hover, .searchform .form-control:focus {
   width: 170px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Mega menu using bootstrap, width search bar </p>
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
<span class="toggle-menu ">MENU</span>
      </button>
    <!--  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a> -->
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home page</a></li>
  
      </ul>
   
 <form action="#" method="get" class="searchform navbar-form" role="search">
 <input type="hidden" value="search" name="view">
 <div class="input-group">
 <input type="text"  name="searchword" required class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
  </div>
 </div>
    </form>
  
     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
</div>
```